# getting error after migrating application from mysql to oracle

Tags: grails, groovy, oracle11g

We are using grails with groovy and recently changed database from MySQL to Oracle 11g. We took care of table names like USER, RESOURCE to make it something else, remapped the new names in the domain classes.

I also added some default data in roles from mysql table(for spring security to work) and inserted one user 'admin' manually in GRAUSER table (renamed from USER). 
The server does start up in Netbeans

But when I try to login I get the following error

> ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter ORA-00904: "THIS_"."password": invalid identifier

Not able to debug the cause of this. Let me know if any more details/code is needed to review, but I need to be able to login to the application.

Comment: It would help to see the class definition and schema of the domain object causing the error.

Comment: Hi,  Found out the issue actually, in domain class for user static mapping = {
        table 'GRAUSER'
        password column: '`password`'
    } . The back tick (`) inside the password was the issue, dont know why it was there previously, removed it and was able to login...

Comment: @pri_dev you should post that as an answer. Also, please don't sign off each of your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your DataSource.groovy file? Below is roughly what mine looks like for connecting to Oracle.

```
dataSource {
    logsql = true
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    username = "user"
    password = "secret"
dialect='org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect'
}

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            //dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:sid"
        }
    }
}
```